# HTTP API call within apache spark filter method

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe which I need to filter based on the condition.

**Condition is:** There is a column `"keyword"` in the dataframe and I need to call an API passing this `keyword` column value. It is to be done for all the `keyword` column values. API will send back one number which I need to match with a threshold value. If it's greater then need to return true else false.

I wrote an **UDF** for that and it looks like below..

```
    val filteredDf = df.filter(apiUdf(col("keyword_text")) === true))

    val apiUdf = udf((topic: String) => {..
     .....
     HTTP API call .. 
     parse the result ... 
     find out the number from the API resposne.. 
     and then compare it with some threshold value and return true/false
```

Here the issue is that I am opening and closing HTTP connection as many times I have number of keywords.. Can someone tell me how to optimize this and also if UDF approach here is fine?

Comment: have you considered using `mapPartitions` instead?

Comment: @shay__ you mean using mapPartitions instead of filter?

Comment: no, instead of the udf. something like `df.mapPartitions(... send http ...).filter(... by response ...)`

Answer (score 0):

`Spark UDFs` are meant to deal with impl complex logic to return value/s.

In a distributed data processing, it is not good design/approach executors calling the external URLs.

- Its scaling issue with the size of the data and no of times
  connection opening/closing.
- And also, In most of the production environments, executor nodes are
  not exposed to internet.

I would advise

1. save/collect all the col("keyword_text")
2. for each keyword call the `HTTP API` (not spark udf) and get the response
3. save the data as some_id, keyword_text, api_result

Now with df1  (some_id, keyword_text, api_result)

You can join df and f1 and filter with the api_result.

I am not sure, if HTTP API takes bulk/batch request (usually most will do) you can consider that approach.

Comment: I completely agree on the fact that you can not call API from UDF as most of the Executor node will not be exposed to internet. Try to create a dataset running on edge node with id,text_keyword and api output. Join with the dataframe and then populate the result again

Comment: You are missing the point, OP has no problem sending HTTP request (maybe to internal service?), the question is about keeping the connection alive.